# Что выполняет выражение {:g} в данном форматировании строки?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть такая строка, непонятно назначение {:g}.

```
print("{:g}".format(distance(x1, y1, x2, y2)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> General format. For a given precision p >= 1, this rounds the number
>   to p significant digits and then formats the result in either
>   fixed-point format or in scientific notation, depending on its
>   magnitude.
>
> The precise rules are as follows: suppose that the result formatted
>   with presentation type 'e' and precision p-1 would have exponent exp.
>   Then if -4 <= exp < p, the number is formatted with presentation type
>   'f' and precision p-1-exp. Otherwise, the number is formatted with
>   presentation type 'e' and precision p-1. In both cases insignificant
>   trailing zeros are removed from the significand, and the decimal point
>   is also removed if there are no remaining digits following it.
>
> Positive and negative infinity, positive and negative zero, and nans,
>   are formatted as inf, -inf, 0, -0 and nan respectively, regardless of
>   the precision.
>
> A precision of 0 is treated as equivalent to a precision of 1. The
>   default precision is 6.

Если коротко и по-русски, то этот спецификатор формата выбирает наиболее удобное представление для числа числа вещественного типа.